# Local LLMs loading, using transformers, is stuck when using AWS EC2 instances from image but not in new instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I am utilizing EC2 instances with the specified parameters:

- Operating System: Amazon Linux - Deep Learning AMI GPU PyTorch 1.13.1 (Amazon Linux 2) / Ubuntu 20.4
- Instance Type: g5.12xl with A10G GPUs
- Python Version: 3.8

I am running Language Model Models (LLMs) using the transformers library. When I set up a new instance and run the process, everything functions correctly (including the ability to freely turn the instance on and off). However, if I create an image from the original instance and then run it on a new instance with the exact same configuration, the process becomes stuck during the model loading phase. There are no errors; it simply hangs (while the tokenizer loads properly).

During image creation, I first shut down the instance (I also tried it while the instance was on), wait for the image creation process to complete, and subsequently create the new instance.

Do you have any insights into the potential cause of this issue?